# Pandas: apply a specific function to columns and create column in new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1`, like this:

```
date        sentence
29/03/1029  i like you
.....
```

I want to create new dataframe `df2` like this:

```
date         verb    object
29/03/2019   like    you
....
```

with the function like this:

```
def getSplit(df1):
    verbList = []
    objList  = []
    df2 = pd.DataFrame()
    for row in df1['sentence']:
        verb = getVerb(row)
        obj  = getObj(row)
        verbList.append(verb)
        objList.append(obj)
    df2 = df1[[date]].copy
    df2['verb'] = verbList
    df2['object'] = objList
    return df2
```

my function run well, but it's slow. Could someone help me improve the function so that can run faster?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can Use `apply` method of pandas to process fast:-

```
getverb(row):
    pass  # Your function
getobj(row):
    passs # Your function
df2 = df1.copy()  # Making copy of your dataframe.

df2['verb'] = df2['sentence'].apply(getverb)
df2['obj'] = df2['sentence'].apply(getobj)
df2.drop('sentence', axis=1, inplace=True)  # Droping sentence column
df2
```

I hope it may help you. (accept and upvote answer)

Comment: do you mean `df2['verb'] = df1['sentence'].apply(getverb)`?

Comment: @elisa No I meant `df1`. If you do not want to change anything in your `df1` then make a copy of `df1` first and then use that copy. I have modified my code you can see it